# Creating a grammar out of a regular language

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language

I have some problems to figure out a grammar for this special language, hope you could help:
The language is:
Σ={x,y,z}
A = { w | w ∈ Σ^∗ ∧ |w|_x mod 2 >= |w|_y mod 2 }

Because this one is so hard i tried first to put all properties together in one grammar, so |w|_x mod 2 >= |w|_y mod 2 and w ∈ Σ^∗ , but without getting all combination like cacbcacb etc

What I get is something like: ccccc...caa...abcbbbcc and than i use
ac -> ca etc to change the combination and to get every word I want.

But could we do some context free grammar too?

My solucion

```
S → G | U | c | cS | ɛ
G → AGB | ɛ | cG
A → ɛ | a | cA
B → ɛ | bb | cB
U → ab | DaUbE | cU
D → a
E → b
ab → ba
ba → ab
ac → ca
ca → ac
bc → cb
cb → bc
```

Very ungly.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this language is regular, so there is clearly no need for a context-sensitive grammar.

Constructing a regular expression is tedious and not particularly useful for the task of finding a context-free grammar. It's easier to work directly from the state machine, particularly so in this case because there are only four states.

Converting a state machine into a CFG is almost trivial. Each state becomes a non-terminal, and you can read the productions off the state transitions. If state `P` has a transition to state `Q` on symbol `a`, the CFG has the production `Q -> P a`. The start symbol then has a unit production to each final state. And that's it.